# How can I reduce the memory usage of my python3 scripts on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2?

Tags: python, pi-zero, cron, performance, memory

I created 9 python scripts that I run as cron jobs.

When I run them on a VirtualBox virtual machine running Ubuntu Server 20.04 with 512MB of RAM with a single processor, everything runs smoothly and only a reasonable amount of memory is used by each job (the virtual machine is hosted on a Windows 10 physical machine).

When I try to run the same scripts on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 running Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 with 512MB of RAM, each job consumes a lot of memory.  I was not able to run more than 3 out of the 9 jobs concurrently without the Pi becoming inaccessible by SSH because all the available memory is being consumed by the 3 jobs.  CPU-wise, everything seems fine.

Is there a way to optimize python, the scripts, or the Pi to get performance similar to the ones on the virtual machine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is because they are running on different architecture.

Comment: This is very possible.  But is there anything I can do to optimize performance on the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 architecture other than upgrading it to a Pi 3 or 4?

Comment: Pi zero is already very slow. Overriding is not really a good option because this chipset can't handle that much processing speed.

Comment: Let me [google that](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=reducing+memory+footprint+of+python+jobs&atb=v278-1&ia=web) for you.

Comment: Maybe the only solution is to upgrade to a more powerful Pi after all.  Unfortunately, they are hard to find these days.